# Dataweave JSON filter

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb

I am trying to select data from a JSON request based on one of the field

```
[
    {
        "Field1": "data1",
        "Field2": "set1",
        "Field3": "reset1"
    },
    {
        "Field1": "data2",
        "Field2": "set2",
        "Field3": "reset2"
    },
    {
        "Field1": "data3",
        "Field2": "set3",
        "Field3": "reset3"
    },
    {
        "Field1": "data4",
        "Field2": "set4",
        "Field3": "reset4"
    }
]
```

I want to select string value of field3 where field2 is "set3". That is "reset3".

DWL I tried:

```
payload.Field3 filter (payload.Field2 ==["set3"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use this DW expression:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload filter ($.Field2=="set3") map {
    Field3: $.Field3
}
```

Result:

```
[
   {"Field3": "reset3"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like this:

```
<logger level="ERROR" message="Field3:::: #[(payload filter ($.Field2 =='set3'))[0].Field3]" />
```

Filter returns array since the array selector `[0]` if there is chance of more than one result you may want to change the expression.

Comment: This doesnot work i am getting NULL assigned to payload. However if i use setPayload after the transformation to extract the value then it is working fine. As good practice i want to handle this in Dataweave code...

Comment: that is dataweave code. that is just a logger to print the value for demo. use set-payload etc if you want to set the value somewhere